# If something weighs 25 kg, how do I find the mass of the object?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, mass, weight

> An object is falling and it weighs 25 kg (on a scale, presumably). What is its mass?

I know that weight is measured in Newtons and mass in kilograms, but what if a problem states that something weighs in kilograms? Would I still use $\text w=mg$?

Comment: Could you please add your actual problem in your question so that we could say something useful..?

Comment: An object is falling and it weighs 25 kgs. What is its mass? That's the question. It's a tricky one - do I use w=mg, or do I just say 25kg?

Comment: Sounds like a trick question. 25kg is a measure of mass, so that's the answer. In everyday usage the word *weight* often means *mass*, so the wording of the question isn't completely wrong, although in Physics *weight* normally refers to the measure of gravitational force on an object, which can vary depending on where it is located.

Comment: Yeah, it's a tricky question. I'll go with 25 kg. Thanks :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen some books use kg for kgf (kilogram-force), even though they shouldn't have conflated them.

But in this case it's not too harmful: if 25 kg means mass, *as it should*, then it the answer is direct. On the other hand, if 25 kg really means 25 kilogram-force, then the answer is the same under the assumption of standard gravity, because $1\,\text{kgf}$ is by definition $(1\,\text{kg})(9.80665\,\text{m/s}^2)$, the weight of 1 kg under 1 standard gravity.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I should mention something (related to the g-force)...

As an object is under the free-fall due to *gravity*, acceleration $a$  equals the acceleration due to gravity $g$ and thereby, the mass of the object measured would be the same. These are the consequences of inertial mass & gravitational mass. Whenever you try to measure the mass of the free-falling object, you should have to move accordingly with the rest frame of the object. The resulting effect is - You would measure the mass *again & again*. This shows the fact that, The weight is zero during a free-fall.

---

Hence, there's a misconception with your question. The mass would be definitely the same.

This Wiki article on [Weightlessness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weightlessness) would be useful...

Answer (score 0):

The weight of an object is a measurement of how hard a force(in our case gravity) is pulling on an object. so W = mg, where W - is the weight. in our case W is G (Gravitational force)
So G = mg => m = G/g => m = 25/9.8 => m = 2.5 kg.
If you're problem states that weight is measured in kg, then it is definitely wrong. Weight is measured in Newtons and mass in kg

Comment: Instead of using reserved letters (fundamental constants) like $G,c,h$, one could make use of common terms like $F$ itself for *Force*. You could differentiate those by using subscripts ($F_g$ *like that*...)

Comment: I agree that using you're form might be a better approach to understand the concept. But in terms of physics, when you solve a problem for an exam, you should use those fundamental constants. It's like a universal language

Comment: Nothing *so important*, I just pointed out that you're assuming $G$ as gravitational force. It's not a big deal. But, some users would be confused "the moment they see it..!" That's all :-)

Answer (score 0):

weight is the mass of things in 1 G (subjected to earth gravitational force) , the scales we use on earth, measures the force (mass x 9.8m/ss) and then divide it to 9.8 . so if your mass is 100 Kg , the force your body causing on the scale is 9800 Newton but i've never seen a scale that works that way. a 25 Kg object, will always be a 25 Kg , and the only proof to that is if you try to change it's direction , exert force and see how much effect that force caused

Answer (score -1):

There are different system of units like gravitational,SI, MKS. I have seen in some text as slug as the unit of mass in gravitational system.So mass of 25 kg weight is 25/9.81 slug of mass.